# function that erase itself after work. vba

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

i want to write something like this:

```
Public Function functionThatEraseHerself()
    functionThatEraseHerself = "here is some work"
    'ActiveCell.value = ActiveCell.value
End Function
```

how it now
[image: how it now]

how it must to be
[image: how it must to be]

Comment: **important**
this function will be called from book, not from vba code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is generally not possible to change cell values from a user defined function called by a formula.

Nevertheless there is a nasty workaround using `Evaluate`

```
Option Explicit

'=functionThatEraseHerself()
Public Function functionThatEraseHerself()
    Dim ReturnValue As String
    ReturnValue = "here is some work"

    ' write the value to the cell that called this function
    Application.Caller.Parent.Evaluate "ReplaceWithValue(" & Application.Caller.Address & ", """ & ReturnValue & """)"
End Function

' helper procedure that is called by evaluate
Public Sub ReplaceWithValue(ByVal Cell As Range, ByVal Value As Variant)
    Cell.Value2 = Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Very cute. The `Evaluate` trick is well known but I like this application of it.

Comment: **Your solution work perfect.** thanks a lot. 
But it's impossible to pass an array in Return Value.
```
Public Function functionThatEraseHerself()
    Application.Caller.Parent.Evaluate "getValue(" & Application.Caller.Address & ")"
End Function
' helper procedure that is called by evaluate
Public Sub getValue(ByVal Cell As Range)
    ' write the value to the cell that called this function
    Cell.Value2 = "somehow i will change cell in to a range and pass the array"
End Sub
```

Comment: @Vitalii I don't get what the problem is. Either edit your original question and add a description of your issue there (including an example of what you did and what happened) or even better open up a new question, as this one is already answered.